# PostgreSQL Field that maps to a XML Property

Tags: java, json, spring

We are building a WebSite that is 100% data driven.  All possible field names will be in PostgreSQL and all values for those fields are coming from a Web Service.  The end user will have the ability to build their own page, by clicking on fields that they want on their screen.  I'm trying to come up with the best way to have the text field in PostgreSQL to relay the full mapping in the XML data that's coming back from the Web Service.   Should I use root\property1\subproperty and just have something loop through breaking it down from XML or is there a more effective way?

EDIT: Replaced JSON with XML.   I've been working with JSON so much lately, I misspoke and said JSON, when these REST Web Services return XML.

EDIT2: I found kind of a solution, but as you can see in the below example, if the node name exists twice, then it will return as two nodes.  I need to figure out if I should stored in DB as newnode2\firstName, I then should loop through nodes, looking for newnode2 first, then looping through to find firstName.  I remember many years ago using an XML object in .NET were I could just do something like a @nodex\subnode and get values..  I might be thinking to hard here.

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    Document doc = null;
    try 
    {  
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = builder.parse( new InputSource( new StringReader( "<response><responseStatus>Success</responseStatus><dataSet name=\"myvalue\"><newnode><firstName>John</firstName><lastName>Smith</lastName></newnode><newnode2><firstName>Bob</firstName><birthDate>11/11/1965</birthDate></newnode2></dataSet></response>" )) );

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("firstName");
        Node n;
        String value;

        for(int i=0; i<nList.getLength(); i++)
        {
            n = nList.item(i);
            value = n.getTextContent();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
```

Comment: Just curiosity: why you don't make use of any document-based NoSQL database, such as MongoDB? Those are intended for the purposes you are suggesting.

Comment: You might also want to look into a dynamic template engine like Apache Velocity.

Comment: @russellhoff Business requirements..  I work for a finance company that has to create approvals after a major security break down of the product and how much support of the product exists.   They have already told us NO on MongoDB.

Comment: Ok @Switch, good luck! Anyway, I don't see any trouble in persisting XML within a table in PostgreSQL.

Comment: I guess you could do what you [want](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-xml.html). Choose a Java XML parser and store the XML as a String within an object.

Comment: I'm looking more at the mapping part..   If the XML returned from Web Services is <root><node><subnode>asd</subnode></node><node2><subnode2>aaa</subnode2></node2></root>.   How can I map subnode easily to a PostgreSQL field.   Would having it in PostgreSQL as root\node\subnode be best and just parse it out manually in XML or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I came up with a recursive function.  Please let me know if you see or know of a better way

```
String xml = "<response><responseStatus>Success</responseStatus><dataSet name=\"myvalue\"><newnode><firstName>John</firstName><lastName>Smith</lastName></newnode><newnode2><firstName>Bob</firstName><birthDate>11/11/1965</birthDate></newnode2></dataSet></response>";
String value;
value = getXMLValue(xml, "newnode2/firstName");  //example of multi-node
value = getXMLValue(xml, "birthDate");           //example of going directly to field if it's the only node with that name.
value = getXMLValue(xml, "dataSet/name");        //example of getting attribute
```

Functions:

```
public String getXMLValue(String xml, String searchNodes) {
    String retVal = "";
    String[] nodeSplit = searchNodes.split("/");

    try 
    {  
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        Document doc;
        NodeList nList;

        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = builder.parse( new InputSource( new StringReader( xml )) );

        nList = doc.getElementsByTagName(nodeSplit[0]);
        retVal = GetNode(nList, searchNodes, 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } 

    return retVal;
}

public String GetNode(NodeList nl, String searchNodes, int item)
{
    String retVal = null;
    String findNode = searchNodes.split("/")[item];
    int count = searchNodes.split("/").length;

    item++;

    for(int i=0; i<nl.getLength(); i++) {
        String foundNode = nl.item(i).getNodeName();
        NamedNodeMap nnm = nl.item(i).getAttributes();
        if(nnm!=null && nnm.getLength()>0 && count>item) {
            Node attribute = nnm.getNamedItem(searchNodes.split("/")[item]);
            if(attribute!=null) {
                retVal = attribute.getTextContent();
                break;
            }
        }

        if(foundNode.equals(findNode) && count>item) {
            retVal = GetNode(nl.item(i).getChildNodes(), searchNodes, item);
            break;
        } else if(foundNode.equals(findNode) && count==item) {
            retVal = nl.item(i).getTextContent(); 
            break;
        }
    }

    return retVal;
}
```